# SQL update command with python not working

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm having an issue getting my python script to update my sqlite db.

The first part seems to work fine:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/test/Desktop/my-accounts.db')
currentAccount = None

for row in conn.execute('SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE active=0'):
    currentAccount = row[0]
    print "Checking out: ",currentAccount
    break

if currentAccount is None:
    print "No available accounts"
```

Then this next part I want to take the variable currentAccount and update the row in the db where that value is.

```
else:
    conn.execute('UPDATE accounts SET active=1 WHERE email=?', [currentAccount,])

conn.close()
```

I don't get any errors in the console but the db does not update. The email column is a VARCHAR and the active column is an INT.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION** was to add 
`conn.commit()` after execute()

Comment: I've tried both as a tuple and a list. Neither one successfully updates the db.

Comment: try to add conn.commit() after conn.execute("XXX"). Sometimes sqlite3 doesn't  auto commit the execution.

Comment: I will put the comment as a answer.

Comment: All DB-API 2.0 compatible driver disable auto commit by default.

Answer (score 1):

try to add `conn.commit()` after `conn.execute("XXX")`. Sometimes sqlite3 doesn't auto commit the execution.

Comment: It's not sometime, auto commit is disabled by default